# login form with multiple users PHP

Tags: php, forms

[image: login form]

Hi I know this is a common thing, but I tried reading and searching for answers based on previous questions similar to this here in stackoverflow.

How can I make a login form that redirect to different pages? For example, I tried logging in as admin with the isd.admin, when login successful it shows the admin-homepage.php. while if I login as aviation admin, it shows aviation-homepage.php when login is successful. As of now I only have 1 account which is the isd.admin. What if I wanted 5 accounts with different homepages?

This is my php code:

```
<?php  
session_start();

try  
{
$pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=accountdb","root",""); 
  $pdoConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
  {  
    //Check for empty fields
       if(empty($_POST["UserName"]) || empty($_POST["PassWord"]))  
       {  
            $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            $pdoQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = :UserName AND PassWord = :PassWord";  
            $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);  
            $pdoResult->execute(  
                 array(  
                      'UserName'     =>     $_POST["UserName"],  
                      'PassWord'     =>     $_POST["PassWord"]  
                 )  
            );  
            $count = $pdoResult->rowCount();  
            if($count > 0)  
            {  
                 $_SESSION["UserName"] = $_POST["UserName"];  
                 header("location:homepage.php");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                $message = '<label style="position:absolute;font-weight:bolder;top:20px;left:100px;">
                TRY AGAIN!</label>';  
            }  
       }  
  }  
 }  
 catch(PDOException $error)  
 {  
  $message = $error->getMessage();  
 }  
 ?>
```

And this is my login form:

```
<form method="post">
                <label class="user-label">User:</label> 
                <label class="pass-label">Pass:</label>
              <div class="inputs">
                 <input class="user-input" type="text" name="UserName" placeholder="e.g.,isd.admin" required autofocus>
                 <input class="pass-input" type="PassWord" name="PassWord" placeholder="********">
              </div>
                 <input class="login-btn" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">  
            </form>
```

Comment: Store their homepage as part of the user account, when they login the information will be right there, then use that to direct them to where they go.  Or if you do it by User group, same thing but store it where the group name etc is stored.  Whatever makes sense.  Which of course is all to Broad for SO.

Comment: Seconded. And don't store plain text passwords in a database. Use `password_hash` and `password_verify`.